# Get rid of navigation toolbar beamer in Table of contents slide Singapore theme

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, header-footer, themes, navigation

I'm using Singapore theme and I would like to get rid of the navigation toolbar (header and footer) in the table of contents page using beamer.

How can I do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `plain` option for the frame:

```
\documentclass[ ]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{A test section}
\begin{frame}test \end{frame}
\section{Another test section}
\begin{frame}test \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result, showing the frame with the ToC and a regular frame:

[image]